# Partition java streams in categories

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a `stream<A>`, where

```
class A {
  String category();
  // ...
}
```

I would like to get a `map<String, list<A>>`, where the original stream is partitioned into sublists based on the value of category(). It is pretty trivial to have it implemented using a for loop, but is it possible to get a more elegant solution harnessing java streams?

EXAMPLE:

Given `{[a, xyz], [a, zyx], [b, abc]}`, I would like to get a map:

```
a -> {[a, xyz], [a, zyx]}
b -> {[b, abc]}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [groupingBy collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-).

`stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::category));`