# Partition and map java streams in categories

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

This question is a sort-of follow-up to [Partition java streams in categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43609324/partition-java-streams-in-categories#43609366)

I have a `stream<A>`, where

```
class A {
  String category();
  String data();
}
```

I would like to get a `map<String, list<String>>`, where the original stream is partitioned into sublists based on the value of `category()`, and then mapped to only extract the `data()`. It is pretty trivial to have it implemented using a for loop, but is it possible to get a more elegant solution harnessing java streams?

EXAMPLE:

Given `{[a, xyz], [a, zyx], [b, abc]}`, I would like to get a map:

```
a -> {xyz, zyx}
b -> {abc}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a slightly different `groupBy`

```
  stream.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(A::getCategory, 
         Collectors.mapping(A::data, Collectors.toList()));
```